# Simple DIV float / stack issue (fixed right, flexible left, media rule)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am almost there, but looks like one property is missing or wrong.

I want to embed two iFrames: 
- left side: a youtube video (witdh flexible)
- right side: a youtube live chat (fixed width 200px)

The @media rule already works. However for the desktop view the second div (chat) stays below the first div (video), whereas it should be on the same line. This is the problem I can't solve. Can somebody be as kind and tell me the trick to bring the chat next to the video?

http://jsbin.com/waxaxa/1/edit?html,css,output

```
.wrapper {
 border : 2px dotted #ccc; padding: 2px; 
}

.wrapper div {
width: 100%; 
 min-height: 200px;
 padding: 10px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden; 
}

#video { background-color: red; float:none; width:auto;}
#chat { background-color: gray;position: }

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
   .wrapper {
    height: auto;width: auto; overflow: hidden; // clearing 
   }
   #video {float:none; margin-right: 200px;}
   #chat { width: 200px; float: right; }
}
```

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change Code Like This :**

```css
.wrapper { 
 border : 2px dotted #ccc; padding: 2px; 
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
}

.wrapper div {
   width: 100%; 
    min-height: 200px;
   padding: 10px;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

#chat {
 background-color: gray;
  width: 20%;
        float: right;
}

#video { 
 background-color: red;
 width: 80%;
 float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   #chat,#video {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;

   }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="video">video</div>
    <div id="chat">chat</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. thanks @ehsan